# What is the performance impact of disabling NCQ?

Tags: linux, centos7, ssd

Our cluster system runs currently under CentOS7 with SSDs and NCQ disabled. What kind of a performance drop is to be expected within an i/o-heavy usage scenario?

I'm not expecting a precise answer because I know it largely depends on the application, hardware, and network (just an idea would be great).

Comment: Well, have you tested it?

Comment: it's an experimental environment. doing the benchmarks takes some time. Just wanted to know what to to expect theoretically because I can't find any decent documentation.

Answer (score 9):

NCQ is a technology that lets drives re-order the order in which read and write requests are serviced.

SSDs save you the seek times hard drives are plagued by, but actually reading from and writing to a NAND die is not especially fast. SSDs get around this by reading and writing to multiple NAND dies in parallel.

In order to achieve this SSDs rely on three kinds of strategies: For large IO request the split the request across multiple dies, by splitting it up and writing parts of the data to separate dies in parallel. For reads the data is, hopefully, also split across dies and can be read back in parallel.

For small IO write loads SSDs usually cache a bunch of them in on board memory and the write the whole slew of them out to different NAND dies in parallel. This is why SSDs can have such high random write performance.

For small IO reads, or mixed workloads, the SSD will service the request in the command queue out of order trying to keep as many NAND dies working in parallel as possible. The SSD can only do this if NCQ is enabled. This can make a huge difference in IO heavy work-loads. For AHCI I've seen up to 10x difference, and for NVMe over 100x.

If you've ever seen benchmarks of an SSD from a benchmarking application like CrystalDiskMark or similar you can see that they usually provide 4k random read results both with and without queue depth. If NCQ is disabled the difference between these two numbers is small, with NCQ enable it is huge. For example, [this Bit-tech review](http://www.bit-tech.net/hardware/storage/2015/11/11/samsung-ssd-950-pro-review/3), put the QD1 4k random read results for the Samsung 950 PRO 512GB (a NVMe drive) at 60MB/s, but the QD32 4k random read results for the same drive are 1261 MB/s.

Answer (score 5):

NCQ is here to rearrange queued read/write operation in order to minimize heads seeks, maximizing performance. A good benchmark with mechanichal disks and NCQ can be found [here](http://www.ilsistemista.net/index.php/linux-a-unix/41-a-look-at-how-ncq-software-queue-and-i-o-schedulers-impact-disk-performance.html)

However, contrary to commond belive, NCQ is even more important for SSDs. The reason is that while they have no heads, due to their very low latency command queueing become really critical to extract maximum performance.

Think about that: if AHCI only had a single 32-entries queue, NVMe has 64k queues with 64k entries each.

Answer (score 0):

NCQ helps the disc to rearrange sectors read/write operations to favor speed. With the target of less head movements. In case you are using an SSD instead of a rotating magnetic disk, the NCQs speed win will be less noticeable.

Comment: But it will be there because it is not only rearrange - NCG also allows a number of operations to be queued up, while traditional SATA, IIRC, is "command/answer" without queue.

Comment: This is incorrect. NCQ allows the SSD to do operations to multiple NAND dies in parallel. Under heacy IO load this can have a huge effect on IOPS, up to 10x on AHCI and even bigger differences with NVMe.